# What is the difference between the default run_list and '_default' environment run_list in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I am a bit confused about how to use environment runlist in chef.
As you can see following role.json. In env_run_lists, you have _default and then we already have the default run_list one. What is the difference? and will the default one run everytime before running the environment run_list?

```
{
  "name": "webserver",
  "default_attributes": {
  },
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "env_run_lists": {
    "_default": [

    ],
    "production": [

    ],
    "dev": [
      "role[base]",
      "recipe[apache]",
      "recipe[apache::copy_dev_configs]"
    ]
  },
  "run_list": [
    "role[base]",
    "recipe[apache]"
  ],
  "description": "The webserver role",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "override_attributes": {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this is quite confusing, especially so since the [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles.html#ruby-dsl) seems to be incorrect with regards to the behaviour I can see by looking at the source.

From reading the [source](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/role.rb#L159) we can see that when the `Role` object is constructed it keys the content of the `run_list` attribute against the _default environment, and then merges the hash with the contents of the `env_run_lists` attribute (overwriting the value for the _default key).

What this means in practice is that if you specify a `run_list` attribute then you *do not* need to include the _default environment in the `env_run_list` attribute. If you choose to include the _default environment in the `env_run_list` attribute then it will overwrite anything defined in the `run_list` attribute.

The one other obvious thing to point out is that if your node is not part of any of the environments defined in the role (_default or otherwise) [it will fall back to using the run_list for the _default environment](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/role.rb#L86).

Answer (score 2):

> What this means in practice is that if you specify a run_list attribute then you do not need to include the _default environment in the env_run_list attribute.

I don't have 50 reputation so I can't comment on Jared Russell's answer, but if I have this in my role definition:

```
common_run_list = ["recipe[something]", "recipe[something_else]"]

run_list(common_run_list)

env_run_lists(
    "dev" => common_run_list + ["recipe[another_thing]"]
)
```

Then I get the following error:

> [2014-02-04T16:38:57-08:00] ERROR: _default key is required in env_run_lists.

So I had to specify the _default key in the env_run_lists even though my run_list is specified.